# Sum With Inner Join Group by Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I have two tables, `Master` and `Child.` I need the sum of column `Cash` in the `Master` table and also I am referring the `Child` table to match certain conditions.

`Master` Table:

```
 ID    CASH        BillDate     
 1     100         22-02-2014      
 2     200         22-02-2014
```

`Child` Table:

```
ChildID MasterID
 1      1
 2      1
 3      2
```

My Query:

```
select CONVERT(varchar,BillDate,103) as BillDate,SUM(cash)as ByCash 
from childdetails CD 
inner join MasterDetails MD on MD.ID=CD.MasterID
where CONVERT(varchar,BillDate,103)='22/02/2014' 
group by BillDate
```

My Incorrect Output:

```
BillDate        ByCash
22/02/2014      400
```

**The correct output should be 300 in `ByCash`, but I'm not sure why its being calculated to be 400.**

Comment: 100+100+200=400. How do you get 300? Which of the child records do you exclude?

Comment: Don't convert date to string. Convert string to date.

Comment: I have clearly Mentioned that I need the sum of column 'Cash' in the Master table purely depends upon master table.....

Comment: @Pradeep If you just need the sum of the cash in the master table why do you link the child table at all? `select billdate, sum(cash) from masterdetails group by billdate` could do that. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that your Child Table counts the MasterID twice. Try selecting the Child table as a CTE with a row_number, partitioned by MasterID to filter out duplicates:

```
select
    CONVERT(varchar,BillDate,103) as BillDate,
    SUM(cash)as ByCash
from    (
        select *,
            row_number() over(partition by MasterID order by ChildID) dedupe
        from childdetails
        ) CD inner join MasterDetails MD on MD.ID=CD.MasterID
where
    CONVERT(varchar,BillDate,103)='22/02/2014'
    and CD.dedupe = 1
group by BillDate
```

Comment: yes i knew that masterid in child table was repeated twice so only i didn't get exact output but your query is correct..can u explain purpose of assigning CD.dedupe = 1 in where condition.....let me know

Comment: CD.dedupe = 1 returns the first in a series of matching MasterIDs. There may be instances where a MasterID has no duplicate. CD.dedupe = 1 will return those as well.

Comment: If I have answered your question, please consider marking mine as the answer and voting it up. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT BillDate, SUM(Cash) FROM MasterDetails GROUP BY BillDate
```

If it isn't, please clarify exactly what your expected output is.

Comment: I need to match child Table compulsory For obtaining Other certain condition,So As Per Your Query i can get the output but i need to match child table to get exact output....

Comment: @Pradeep I feel stupid now, but I don't quite get what you want the output to look like. If you could add an example of the output you desire I'm sure this can be solved.

Comment: Actual problem is masterid in child table was repeated, i have used group by with join so i am getting cash as 400....